# Invoking OpenShift Service Catalog REST resources

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

In the context of the OpenShift 3.7 [Service Catalog](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/architecture/service_catalog/index.html), what would it look like if I wanted to create Service Instances outside of the OpenShift Console UI?

I.e. from a terminal on my local machine, if I wanted to create an instance of a Service Class available in the Service Catalog (e.g. run and an [APB](https://github.com/ansibleplaybookbundle/ansible-playbook-bundle) available via the [Ansible Service Broker](https://github.com/openshift/ansible-service-broker)) what would the REST resource call look like (assuming there is a REST API available)?

An example using `curl` would be appreciated.

The assumption is that there is a REST API available for Service Catalog related resources. If this is not true, what is another integration pattern that would satisfy the requirement above? Does the `oc` CLI tool support Service Catalog commands?

Comment: Based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65cyANDCazY, need to confirm but `/apis/servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterservicebrokers/...` and friends might be what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best examples I can point you to are the ones from [the incubator repo walkthrough](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/service-catalog/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md).  You'll probably be most interested in the [example ServiceInstance](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/service-catalog/blob/master/contrib/examples/walkthrough/ups-broker.yaml) and example [ServiceBinding](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/service-catalog/blob/master/contrib/examples/walkthrough/ups-instance.yaml).

The service-catalog has a normal Kubernetes API server and the resources work like the other resources you're familiar with do.  For example, you could make a new instance of a service in the openshift console and poke around in the API server using:

```
$ kubectl get serviceinstances
```

Note, `oc get serviceinstances` is another valid form of command to use.

The CLI experience isn't fantastic for `kubectl get` for these resources yet, but `describe` works very well.  In a future release of service-catalog the CLI experience for `kubectl get` will be improved.